# Why can't I write the size() function as a condition in the while loop?

Tags: c++

when I learning the KMP algorithm. I found out if I write the size() function as a condition in the while loop I will get the wrong result.

I found if I set size() function as condition. It can't enter the while loop in second time.

For example, if haystack="hello" and needle="ll". The correct answer is 2. But in this code. I get -1 as result.Because I found when I enter while loop in first time. Value of j become '-1'. But value of i still less than haystack.size() and same time value of j still less than needle.size().

why can't I write the code in this form.

This is my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int strStr(string haystack, string needle) {
        if (needle.size() > haystack.size())
            return -1;
        if (haystack == "" || needle == "")
            return 0;
        std::vector<int> next(needle.size(), 0);
        getNext(next, needle);

        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (i < haystack.size() && j < needle.size()) // it is question location
        {
            if (j == -1 || haystack[i] == needle[j])
            {
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            else
                j = next[j];
        }

        if (j == needle.size())
            return i - j;
        else
            return -1;

    }

    void getNext(std::vector<int>& next, string needle)
    {
        next[0] = -1;
        int i = 0, j = -1;
        while (i < needle.size()-1)
        {
            if (j == -1 || needle[i] == needle[j])
            {
                ++i;
                ++j;
                next[i] = j;
            }
            else
                j = next[j];
        }

    }
};
```

If I write this code. It's correct

```
class Solution {
public:
    int strStr(string haystack, string needle) {
        if (needle.size() > haystack.size())
            return -1;
        if (haystack == "" || needle == "")
            return 0;
        std::vector<int> next(needle.size(), 0);
        getNext(next, needle);

        int i = 0, j = 0;
        int p = haystack.size();//look at this
        int q = needle.size(); //look at this
        while (i < p && j < q)
        {
            if (j == -1 || haystack[i] == needle[j])
            {
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            else
                j = next[j];
        }

        if (j == needle.size())
            return i - j;
        else
            return -1;

    }

    void getNext(std::vector<int>& next, string needle)
    {
        next[0] = -1;
        int i = 0, j = -1;
        while (i < needle.size()-1)
        {
            if (j == -1 || needle[i] == needle[j])
            {
                ++i;
                ++j;
                next[i] = j;
            }
            else
                j = next[j];
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with using the result of `std::string::size()` as part of a `while` loop condition. The problem is somewhere in your program logic.

Comment: Perhaps this is a `signed`/`unsigned` comparison issue. You can't compare a negative value with `size()` since it returns an unsigned value. The negative value get's converted to the unsigned type, usually making it very large. The fact that the first line in the loop body has `if (j == -1`... leads me to believe this is the case.

Comment: No, you can see my second code. Two program logic is same. I just set variable p and q to replace the haystack.size() and needle.size().

Comment: They aren't the same. In the first your loop condition compares an `int` with a `std::size_t` while in the second example your loop condition compares an `int` with an `int`. `std::string::size()` doesn't return `int`.

Comment: Is all of this code required to show us the issue? Can you try to create a Minimal, Verifiable, Complete example that we can run? (and in whittling down the code you may even spot your own issue!)

Comment: Yes, You solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that stands out to me is your comparison of j to -1, telling me you expect it at some point to get negative (presumably when there is no next value.)
Assuming j actually is negative, your loop is expected to terminate.

But it won't.

There's a nasty bug of comparing signed and unsigned values, which has surprising results.
Note, (-1 < 5u) is **false** (really!!!), because the negative int is promoted to unsigned, and -1 represented as unsigned is max unsigned.  So the loop doesn't terminate when it should.

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
while (i < haystack.size() && j < needle.size()) // BUG: signed/unsigned mixture
{
    if (j == -1 || haystack[i] == needle[j])
    {
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    else
        j = next[j];
}
```

Contrast that to when you store the size in an int, then you are doing integer comparisons and the loop terminates properly:

```
    int p = haystack.size();
    int q = needle.size();
    while (i < p && j < q) // *** int to int comparison == good
    {
```

Comment: Note that if you build with warnings enabled, the compiler would have told you this.

Comment: Wow, I miss the warnings information. It's my mistake. Thank you two guy and François Andrieux. It's my first question in stackoverflow. I will notice the warning information and simplify my code if I have some problem in the next time.

Comment: @GemTaylor Good point!  I meant to bring that up but forgot.    I always enable warnings as errors, and enable as many warnings as my compiler allows.  It definitely catches these types of errors.